# Quadratic Taylor series using epsilon expression

Tags: taylor-expansion

Hello I have a question about Taylor series. While studying Mathematical Statistics written by Hogg, I found this expression below (page 314).

$$m(t)=m(0)+m'(0)t+\frac{m''(\epsilon)t^2}{2}$$

where $0<\epsilon<t$

Could you tell me how $\epsilon$ can be used?

As expression above and Taylor series, the equality below is right.

$$\frac{m''(\epsilon)t^2}{2} = \frac{m''(0)t^2}{2}+\frac{m'''(0)t^3}{3!} + \frac{m''''(0)t^4}{4!} + \dots $$

Why?

Comment: Did you mean $m'(0)t$?

Comment: This is [Taylor's theorem with Lagrange Remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) (for the special case $k=1$ and $a=0$ using Wikipedia's notation).

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the expression is one form of Taylor's theorem with an exact expression for the remainder.  It is derived from the mean value theorem as follows:

Suppose $f(x)$ is $n$ times differentiable in the closed interval $[0,a]$ (at the ends of the interval we suppose $f$ has $n$ left or right one-sided derivatives as applicable).  Then for any $t, 0 < t \leqslant a$ there exists $h$ (dependent on $t$) with $0 < h < t$ such that
\begin{align}
f(t) = f(0) + f'(0) t + f''(0) \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + f^{(n-1)}(0)\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+f^{(n)}(h)\frac{t^n}{n!}.
\end{align}
The formula you quote is the case where $n=2$ and the interval is  $[0,t]$.

It can be used where $f$ is twice differentiable in an interval containing $[0,t]$ (allowing one-sided derivatives at the end points) to obtain a linear approximation of the form $f(t) \bumpeq f(0)+f'(0)t$ where the error is then given by $f''(\varepsilon)t^2/2$.  The error term may not immediately be of much use since $\varepsilon$ is not explicitly revealed but, for example, if $f''$ is known to be bounded then you can obtain a worst case estimate of the error size.

Higher order Taylor series give approximations for $f$ as a quadratic or cubic and so on, each with an associated error expression.

Taylor's theorem with this form of final term can be derived by defining the function,
$$
g(x) = f(t)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(t-x)^kf^{(k)}(x)}{k!}
$$
which is differentiable on $[0,t]$ with $g(t)=0$, and then applying the mean value theorem to the function,
$$\phi(x) = g(x) -\frac{t-x}{t}g(0)$$ so
constructed top make $\phi(0) = \phi(t) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your endeavor really helped me so much! That question is what I want to understand for long time. Thanks for again!

Comment: No problem, and if you found it useful you can accept it.